# what happens if I change the values of a list that is used as dropdownlist in an infopath form?

Tags: 2013, infopath

I want to know what happens in the next scenario:

I got a dropdownlist that comes from a list in sharepoint with the values 1,2,3 and I fill many forms with this data, then I delete this values from the list and convert them in a,b,c that has nothing to do with the former values, what happen to the value saved in the old forms?

Comment: what happens to which values? you say that you delete this values.

Comment: I delete the values from the list, but what happens with the values I recorded in the form? (in the xml), when I reopen the form what values appears? it respect the recorded value even is not in the current list?